# How to prove that $\text{gcd}(a_1, a_2, ..., a_n) = \text{gcd}(a_1, a_1 + a_2, ..., a_1 + a_2 + ... + a_n)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

How is it possible that $\text{gcd}(a_1, a_2, ..., a_n) = \text{gcd}(a_1, a_1 + a_2, ..., a_1 + a_2 + ... + a_n)$? This is not a homework or anything so an intuitive proof would be enough, but I can't seem to wrap my head around it. I found this proposition on a codeforces problem:
[Solution Statement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/75vZW.png)

The problem is here:
https://codeforces.com/contest/1925/problem/B

Comment: How is it possible? Look first at the case $n=2$. This is easy to understand. See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/483862/how-do-i-prove-gcda-b-gcdab-b), or better [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/23316/prove-gcda-b-gcda-b-at?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: $\gcd(b_1, ..., b_n) = \gcd(b_1, \gcd(b_2, ..., b_n))$ so it follows by induction

Comment: @DietrichBurde I recognize that, but I just don't see how it generalizes to 3+ elements

Comment: It generalises by induction.

Comment: $\gcd$ is just infimum in a certain partial order, and from that the equality I wrote above is obvious, it reads $\inf\{b_1 \inf\{b_2, ..., b_n\}\} = \inf\{b_1, ..., b_n\}$.

Comment: By the [proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/95825/242) in the dupe, a gcd remains the same if we subtract one argument from any number of the others, so subtract $\,{\rm arg}_1 = a_1$ from  all args after it, then subtract the new $\,{\rm arg}_2 = a_2$ from all args after it, etc, terminating with all $\,{\rm arg}_k = a_k.\,$ Or, simpler, working in reverse order: make each highest index $\,{\rm arg}_k = a_k\,$ by subtracting the prior arg, then do the same for the prior arg, etc. $\ \ $

Comment: The latter method boils down to $\,(b_1,b_2,b_3,\ldots,b_n)  = (b_1,\, b_2\!-\!b_1,\, b_3\!-\!b_2,\ldots, b_n\!-\!b_{n-1}),\,$ in the OP special case $\,b_1 = a_1,\ b_{n} = b_{n-1} + a_n,\ \  $

Comment: meanwhile, if $v$  is a column vector of integers with the gcd of them $g,$   and $M$  is a square matrix of integers with determinant $\pm 1,$   then the gcd of the elements in the column vector $Mv$  is also $g.$  Your matrix $M$  has all ones on or below the diagonal, all zero above the diagonal

Comment: The two sequences are related linearly by a triangular integer matrix having ones in the diagonal and so is invertible.

Comment: The remarks in the prior two comments are clarified when one studies ideals, e.g. see  [unimodular transformations](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/863501/242). The connection is that the ideal $(a_1,\ldots, a_n) = (d)$ is generated by any gcd $d$ of the $a_i$  because $\Bbb Z$ enjoys a Euclidean division (with remainder) algorithm (i.e. Euclidean $\Rightarrow$ PID). $\ \ $

Answer (score 1):

The greatest common divisor of a set of natural numbers $\{a_1,\dots,a_n\}\subseteq\mathbb N$ is defined as
$$
\gcd(a_1,\dots,a_n)=\max\left\{k\in\mathbb N~\middle|~\forall i\in\{1,\dots,k\}: n\text{ divides }a_i\right\}
$$
To show $\leq$ in your desired equality, you therefore have to show that every natural number that divided $a_1,\dots,a_n$ also divides $a_1,a_1+a_2,\dots,a_1+\dots+a_n$. This follows since if $k$ divides $x$ and $y$ it also divides $x+y$.
Showing $\geq$ is a bit more complicated: Let $k\in\mathbb N$ such that $k$ divides all of $a_1,a_1+a_2,\dots,a_1+\dots+a_n$. By definition, $k$ divides $a_1$. Since $k$ divides $a_1$ and $a_1+a_2$ it also needs to divide $a_2=(a_1+a_2)-a_1$. Since $k$ divides $a_1+a_2$ and $a_1+a_2+a_3$ it similarly needs to divide $a_3$. Continuing in this manner shows that $k$ divides all of $a_1,\dots,a_n$.