# How do I solve this GCD proof

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, modular-arithmetic, gcd-and-lcm

Let $k$ be a positive integer. Prove that for any integer $n>=k+1$, if $k|n$, then $gcd(n,n-k) = k$.

My attempt:

$q_{1}n + q_{2}(n-k) = k$

Also, $k|n = k*u = n$

$q_{1}*k*u + q_{2}(k*u-k) = k$

I don't know what do do after this step

Comment: Are you familiar with the Euclidean algorithm? If so, I suggest you use it.

Comment: If $n=km$, then $n-k=k(m-1)$. Reduce this to finding the GCD of $m$ and $m-1$, and you can finish it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You tell nothing about $q_1$ and $q_2$, so this path leads to nothing.

What you have to show is that $k$ is the maximum common divisor.

The hypothesis tells you $n=mk$, so also $n-k=(m-1)k$. Therefore $k$ is a common divisor of $n$ and $n-k$.

If $h$ is a common divisor of $n$ and $n-k$, then
$$
n=ah,\qquad n-k=bh
$$
and therefore
$$
k=n-(n-k)=ah-bh=(a-b)h
$$
Hence $h\le k$ (actually $h$ is a divisor of $k$).

Comment: I'm confused about how $n-k = (m-1)k$ came from $gcd(n,n-k)=k$

Comment: @Ag_Yog $\gcd(n,n-k)$ is what you have to prove! If $n=mk$, then $n-k=mk-k=(m-1)k$.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that since $k|n$, we have $\gcd(n,k)=\gcd(n,-k)=k$. This is because $k|k$ and $k|n$, and there are no greater divisors of $k$.

Further, it is not to hard to see that $\gcd(a,b)=\gcd(a,a+b)$.
(See for instance, [Prove: $\gcd(a,b) = \gcd(a, b + at)$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/23316/prove-gcda-b-gcda-b-at))

Thus, we have $k=\gcd(n,-k)=\gcd(n,n-k)$, where we used the above fact.